# Error: $resource:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

In my ionic app,I have a service as shown.

```
  .factory('newsFactory',['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource,baseURL) {

      return $resource(baseURL + "news/:id", null, {
                'update': {
                      method: 'PUT'
                 }
      });   


}])
```

Then I inject the above factory in DishDetailController. I want the user to click in a row and get the specific article of my news json array. ie http://localhost:3000/news/1,http://localhost:3000/news/2 and so on.

```
  .controller('NewsController', ['$scope', 'newsFactory', function($scope, newsFactory) {

                    $scope.message = "Loading ...";

                    $scope.newsZero = newsFactory.query(
                                function(response) {
                                    var news = response;
                                        $scope.newsZero = news[0];
                                        console.log($scope.newsZero);

                                },
                                function(response) {
                                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                                });

                                $scope.newsOne = newsFactory.query(
                                function(response) {
                                    var news = response;
                                    $scope.newsOne = news[1];
                                    console.log($scope.newsOne);
                                },
                                function(response) {
                                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                                });

                                $scope.newsTwo = newsFactory.query(
                                function(response) {
                                    var news = response;
                                    $scope.newsTwo = news[2];
                                    console.log($scope.newsTwo);
                                },
                                function(response) {
                                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                                });

                                $scope.newsThree = newsFactory.query(
                                function(response) {
                                    var news = response;
                                    $scope.newsThree = news[3];
                                    console.log($scope.newsThree);
                                },
                                function(response) {
                                    $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                                });

        }])
.controller('NewsDetailsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'newsFactory', function($scope, $stateParams, newsFactory) {

                 $scope.detailedNews = newsFactory.get({
                    id: $stateParams.id
                 })
                 .$promise.then(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.detailedNews = response;

                    },
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                    }
                );


 }]);
```

I can display all of my json objects in card views by using this code.

```
                    <ion-view view-title="News">
                  <ion-content>

                    <div class="card">

                          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.newsdetails({id: newsZero._id})">
                               <img ng-src="{{newsZero.image}}" alt="{{newsZero.image}}">
                              <h2>{{newsZero.title}}</h2>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card">

                          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.newsdetails({id: newsOne._id})">
                               <img ng-src="{{newsOne.image}}" alt="{{newsOne.image}}">
                              <h2>{{newsOne.title}}</h2>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card">

                          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.newsdetails({id: newsTwo._id})">
                               <img ng-src="{{newsTwo.image}}" alt="{{newsTwo.image}}">
                              <h2>{{newsTwo.title}}</h2>

                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card">

                          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" ui-sref="app.newsdetails({id: newsThree._id})">
                               <img ng-src="{{newsThree.image}}" alt="{{newsThree.image}}">
                              <h2>{{newsThree.title}}</h2>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </ion-content>
                </ion-view>
```

But when I click any one of them,I get the error described in the title of this question. How can I fix that error?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg

Comment: What effort have you made to trace the error to a specific line of code?

Comment: I went to link you wrote a while ago. I should be getting back an object not an array,when I click a specific row. I have been trying for the whole evening.

Comment: if you look inside my NewsDetailsController,you will notice that I am using the get function. This is how it should be. But for some reason angular doesn't like that.

Comment: Use `newsFactory.query` for arrays; use `newsFactory.get` for objects.

Comment: This line gives me the error.  $scope.detailedNews = newsFactory.get({
                    id: $stateParams.id
                 })